# Website - How to get data from mysql database and show in table

Tags: mysql, web

I have a HTML website which I want to grab data from mysql, and present it in a table.

Only issue is when the database gets a new entry, I need the website to check for this to present in near real time.

Does anyone know how to do this please?

Thanks in advance,

Shane.

Comment: Use web-sockets or use JS in combination with  AJAX to check for new records with `setInterval()`

Comment: Thanks for that :)